# Mudar a cor de uma tag <td> de um WebGrid mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, css3, webgrid

Esse é o `WebGrid` e preciso mudar a cor de fundo da `Celula` preenchida "EM PROCESSAMENTO": para ***Vermelho***:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .grid {
        margin: 4px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .head {
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .grid th, .grid td {
        border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .alt {
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
        color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

Eu monto as colunas do WebGrid desse jeito no code behid:

```
List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    columns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
    {
        ColumnName = col.ColumnName,
        Header = col.ColumnName,
        Format = (item) =>
        {
            if (valor == "EM PROCESSAMENTO")                                        
            {
                return new HtmlString("<font color='blue'><b>EM PROCESSAMENTO</b></font>"); //Pintar o fundo da Celula em vermelho.
            }                                
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que basta definir uma regra CSS:

```
.grid td.em-processamento {
    background-color: red;
}
```

E usar essa classe na propriedade Style do DataColumn:

```
List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    columns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
    {
        ColumnName = col.ColumnName,
        Header = col.ColumnName,
        Format = (item) =>
        {
            if (valor == "EM PROCESSAMENTO")                                        
            {
                return new HtmlString("<font color='blue'><b>EM PROCESSAMENTO</b></font>"); //Pintar o fundo da Celula em vermelho.
            }                                
        },
        Style = (valor == "EM PROCESSAMENTO") ? "em-processamento" : "";
    });
});
```